# pandas set_index not working as expected for multiple columns

Tags: django, pandas

```
df = im.pd.DataFrame([ 
['abc bank', 'Delhi', 'person a'], 
['abc bank', 'Delhi', 'person b'], 
['abc bank', 'Bombay', 'person c'], 
['abc bank', 'Bombay', 'person d'], 
['abc bank', 'Surat', 'person c'], 
['abc bank', 'Surat', 'person d'], 
['cde bank', 'Delhi', 'person z'], 
['cde bank', 'Delhi', 'person y'], 
['cde bank', 'Bombay', 'person x']  
], 
columns = ['corporation', 'city', 'managers']) 

print('DataFrame with default index\n', df)
```

Then when we do this:

```
df = df.set_index(['corporation', 'city'])

print('\nDataFrame with MultiIndex\n',df)
```

The output we get is:

```
DataFrame with MultiIndex
                    managers
corporation city            
abc bank    Delhi   person a
            Delhi   person b
            Bombay  person c
            Bombay  person d
            Surat   person c
            Surat   person d
cde bank    Delhi   person z
            Delhi   person y
            Bombay  person x
```

What I want is:

```
                    managers
corporation city            
abc bank    Delhi   person a
                    person b
            Bombay  person c
                    person d
            Surat   person c
                    person d
cde bank    Delhi   person z
                    person y
            Bombay  person x
```

So the set_index is grouping the first column of 'corporation' but not the second column of 'city' how can I get this?

Context: I'm doing this to covert pandas df to html with rowspans for first 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

You can start by sorting your two columns (set to be the multiindex) then use [**`pandas.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [**`pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to replace duplicated entries with empty strings :

```
df = df.sort_values(['rollno', 'name']).reset_index(drop=True)
df.loc[df.duplicated(["rollno", "name"]), 'name'] = ''
df.loc[df.duplicated('name'), 'name'] = ''
out= df.set_index(['rollno', 'name'])
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

             physics  botony
rollno name                 
21     Amol       72      67
                  78      69
       Kiku       74      56
22     Ajit       54      76
```

Comment: This is removing values from 2nd column which are mapped to different values in first column. I've edited my question with a better example to explain the use case.